# application which can run every machine

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I created an inventory management system in C# with SQL database, which runs perfectly on my machine. But when I deploy and run it on another machine with SQL server, it gives errors like `server not found`, `not accessible` or `instance not found` etc. How can I do this?

I tried following:

```
SqlConnection con =new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=root;Password=root");

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=root;Password=root");

SqlConnection con =new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=root;Password=root");
```

but none of them worked.

Comment: You need to install sql server localdb or sql server express edition. it is a different install and is not part of the .NET framework

Comment: When you open SQL Management Studio in the machine you deployed your application, what's the server name and the credentials you would use to connect to the database you want to (you said that this machine has a SQL server, I refer to this server.)? DON'T write them in your post or as a comment below !!! This name and credentials should be used in the `new SqlConnection(@"....")`.

Comment: You application requires a local sql server setup on the machine where it runs. SQLExpress is the best option for that. You need to make sure that SQLExpress is installed on the machine and it should have user created on it which is used by application. And instead of using database on the server you need to use mdf file. You need to have the mdf file copied to a specific location as part of the application setup. The application will have the connection string pointing to the file instead of the server.

Answer (score 0):

if you install sql express on machine named 'SERVERTEST', try something like this :

```
SqlConnection con =new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SERVERTEST\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=root;Password=root");
```

or this :

```
SqlConnection con =new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SERVERTEST;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=root;Password=root");
```

Else verify your server name and your named instance into  your install of SQL Server